# FXMLLoader.load() works fine in pre-java 9 style, but fails in modules

Tags: java, fxml, fxmlloader, java-module, javafx-11

I successfully made a simple JavaFX FXML program (in pre-Java 9 style, not module)
I used 3 files and the main class as below:

```
└───javafxfxmldemo
        FXMLDocument.fxml
        FXMLDocumentController.java
        JavaFXFXMLDemo.java
```

Main class

```
public class JavaFXFXMLDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly both in NetBeans 9 and in DOS terminal with javac and java.

Now, I tried to make the same program in Java modules.  Below is my source structure:

```
└───src
    └───com.fxmlapp
        │   module-info.java
        │
        └───com
            └───fxmlapp
                    FXEventModuleDemo.java
                    FXMLDocument.fxml
                    FXMLDocumentController.java
```

module-info.java

```
module com.fxmlapp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    exports com.fxmlapp;
}
```

All the rest of code is identical except the main class name.

It compiles in NetBeans 9 and I also could compile in DOS terminal as below:

```
javac -d mods\com.fxmlapp --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% src\com.fxmlapp\module-info.java src\com.fxmlapp\com\fxmlapp\FXEventModuleDemo.java src\com.fxmlapp\com\fxmlapp\FXMLDocumentController.java
```

After compilation, I placed the **FXMLDocument.fxml** file in the mods directory as below.

```
├───mods
│   └───com.fxmlapp
│       │   module-info.class
│       │
│       └───com
│           └───fxmlapp
│                   FXEventModuleDemo.class
│                   FXMLDocument.fxml
│                   FXMLDocumentController.class
│
└───src
    └───com.fxmlapp
        │   module-info.java
        │
        └───com
            └───fxmlapp
                    FXEventModuleDemo.java
                    FXMLDocument.fxml
                    FXMLDocumentController.java
```

But, it fails to run.  I tried both in NetBeans 9 and in DOS terminal as below:

```
java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX%;mods -m com.fxmlapp/com.fxmlapp.FXEventModuleDemo
```

The error comes from the statement:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

I know, there are many posts with this issue, but I couldn't find a solution to this when the error occurs in java modules.  I don't think it is the file location issue because below statement works.

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

**FXMLLoader.load()** seems doesn't work in modules.

If it works in non-module style, I believe it must work in modules too.

The actual error message is as below; Yes, I saw many questions asking with this error, but I still couldn't find a solution with java modules)  Did I do something wrong with my module-info.java or my compile or run commands?

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/D:/OpenJFX_Demo/FXEventModuleDemo/mods/com.fxmlapp/com/fxmlapp/FXMLDocument.fxml:14

        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
        at com.fxmlapp/com.fxmlapp.FXEventModuleDemo.start(FXEventModuleDemo.java:13)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private javafx.scene.control.Label com.fxmlapp.FXMLDocumentController.label accessible: module com.fxmlapp does not "opens com.fxmlapp" to module javafx.fxml
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleFields(FXMLLoader.java:3479)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.access$3900(FXMLLoader.java:3328)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3444)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3440)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleMembers(FXMLLoader.java:3439)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.getControllerFields(FXMLLoader.java:3378)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1170)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:105)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:865)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:759)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
        ... 17 more
Exception running application com.fxmlapp.FXEventModuleDemo
```

Comment: didn't go through the complete stacktrace...but for *module com.fxmlapp does not "opens com.fxmlapp"*, using `--add-opens` might help there

Comment: @nullpointer where do I put the option?  in javac when compile or in java in run time?  I couldn't see that option neither in javac nor java.

Comment: at execution time, documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624

Comment: @nullpointer The error says **module com.fxmlapp does not "opens com.fxmlapp" to module javafx.fxml**.  So, I added **--add-opens com.fxmlapp/com.fxmlapp=javafx.fxml**.  Now, I can run the program. Thank you for your help.  But, does it mean, we must use **--add-opens** option for every FXML module program?  I still wonder if there is a better way to run FXML module programs.  For example, make a package open in module-info.java ??? Any helps will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by **@nullpointer**:

The error says **module com.fxmlapp does not "opens com.fxmlapp" to module javafx.fxml**.

So, I added **--add-opens com.fxmlapp/com.fxmlapp=javafx.fxml**.  It solveed the problem.

Comment: It would be better to add an `opens com.fxmlapp to javafx.fxml` directive to your module-info file.